# Dynamically retranslate Qt Quick UI

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, translation, qtquick2

I want to dynamically retranslate *Qt Quick* GUI strings.

There is [intrusive trick](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML) to retranslate affected string properties, whose notifications about changes cannot be centralized.

Is it possible to make `qsTr` (and others) to return `string`-like objects, which behaves exactly like `string`, but also behaves like global properties connected to common "valueChanged" signal (which I want to emit, when `QEvent::LanguageChange` in `QCoreApplication` occured).

I think I can use twitching of `Loader`'s `active` property, which contains entire top level GUI element to make all the user-visible strings retranslated, but this approach results in lost of the state of all the items and components, connected to the `Loader` and not differs from complete application restart for me.

Is it possble to create such `myQsTr` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Qt 5.10 onwards, you can call [QQmlEngine::retranslate()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#retranslate) after you have installed a new translator with [QCoreApplication::installTranslator()](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qcoreapplication.html#installTranslator), to ensure that your user-interface shows up-to-date translations.

Answer (score 1):

You could opt to use your own, 100% QML solution like that:

```
// Tr.qml
// also put `singleton Tr Tr.qml` in the qmldir file
pragma Singleton 
import QtQuick 2.7

QtObject {
  function t(s) {
    if (lang === eng) return s
    var ts = lang[s]
    return ts ? ts : s
  }

  property var lang: eng

  readonly property var eng : {
    "hello" : "hello",
    "goodbye" : "goodbye"
  }

  readonly property var ger : {
    "hello" : "hallo",
    "goodbye" : "auf wiedersehen"
  }

  readonly property var esp : {
    "hello" : "hola"
  }
}

// test it out
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import "." // same old singleton bug

ApplicationWindow {
  id: main
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  color: "darkgray"

  Column {
    Text { text: Tr.t("hello") }
    Text { text: Tr.t("goodbye") }
    Button { text: "Eng"; onClicked: Tr.lang = Tr.eng }
    Button { text: "Ger"; onClicked: Tr.lang = Tr.ger }
    Button { text: "Esp"; onClicked: Tr.lang = Tr.esp }
  }
}
```

The different language objects act like a `map<string, string>` and every time you change `lang` this will cause the binding expressions to reevaluate and refresh the value form the current language dictionary.

This solution will also fallback to the default language string if a translation is not found. You can easily customize the behavior and you don't rely on any external tooling. Clean, simple, self-contained and totally under your control.

Comment: Without LinguistTools it is hard to manage multiple languages. Your approach is error-prone in my case - GUI is too big and complex. I want to use text ID based translations.

Comment: Well, it is an either-or scenario. The linguist is ancient and doesn't support dynamic re-translation without reloading the gui.

Comment: Keep in mind it would be trivial to parse and extract all translations via a simple regex, and make a list of all unique translation phrases, then you can use integer based lookup which is even faster, you can easily do external dictionaries loading and all that stuff.

Comment: Qt Linguist allows all you mentioned. Text ID based translations is inherent feature of Qt Linguist. Export to many common (not just TS) formates - is also a function of `lconvert`. Qt Linguist is not only extraction of `qsTr`, `tr` and other stuff - it is also possibility to specify and then to extract many kinds of metainformation from special comments from source code (e.g. `//%`, `//~`, `//:`) with different meaning. Don't know what can I want else from Qt Linguist. Dynamic translation support is not the headache of Qt Linguist. It is totally on `QtGui` side.

Comment: Looking at [this](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_do_dynamic_translation_in_QML) what do you think? I sure it is totally feasible to achieve the desired behaviour just by means of changing the semantics of `qsTr`-like functions in *QML* language.

Comment: It is not trivial to parse and extract all the user-visible strings. Even only specially wrapped ones. Surely I need some kind of `libclang` to do this correctly. Simple regexp is not able to deal with nested quotes into quotes (and with other kinds of regularity) and with raw strings (multiline `R"(123\n456)"`, where `\n` is actual newline character in source code) and maybe there are other downsides.

Comment: Well, if that doesn't work out for you, you are free to pursue other solutions. It works perfectly for me for a gui that is totally dynamic in size, scale, color and text. Also, who has multi-line strings in his gui elements? You obviously do not put lengthy text in the gui directly, you put it in the dictionary and give it an id like `"some info"`, and you put it inside a text control that will warp it according to the gui and font size. I do have quotes thou, and that's simple, use the `'this "string" format'` instead.

Comment: But note the particularity of the code in that answer - you can get reevaluation for a binding expression that doesn't reference the changing property directly. So maybe you can use that to refresh the stock translation as well? Try `property string dummy: ""` and then `text: qsTr("someText" + dummy)` then change the language and force a `dummyChanged()` in QML to get the expression to reevaluate. If that refreshes the text to the new translation you are done and done. See if that works and I will update the answer, because as mentioned, I don't use linguist, so I can't try it myself.